# UICollectionView not asking for data from UICollectionViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've set up `UICollectionView` with custom data source as:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let dataSource = DataSource(storage)
let delegate = DelegateFlow()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

paymentsHistory = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
paymentsHistory.delegate = delegate
paymentsHistory.dataSource = dataSource
paymentsHistory.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

self.view.addSubview(paymentsHistory)
```

Collection view itself is displaying correctly, but no cells appear.

I can see from debug output, that

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

and

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

are never called. Why is that?

Comment: have you tried calling `reloadData()` on collection view after adding it to `self.view`?

Comment: It doesnt do anything @DashAndRest

Comment: it is not calling because of height of collection is zero so you need to check collectionView height .

Comment: @KKRocks constraints are set later in this method. I also have mentioned that collection view is displaying correctly.

Comment: did you check height of collection view. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is it's being de-referenced since the `delegate` and `datasource` in UICollectionView are weak references.

```
weak open var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate?
weak open var dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource?
```

Once you get outside the scope of whatever function you're in, it should be made nil.

It should work if you make it a property of your class.